# Confusion Matrix doesn't show all outputs after NN

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, keras

i worked with the pokerhand dataset from uci machine learning repository, i applied a neural network and everything went fine. Just with the presentation of the confusion matrix, there is a problem.
So here is my code (please ignore my comments, i am german..):

```
# Code reproduzierbar machen
from numpy.random import seed
seed(0)
from tensorflow import set_random_seed
set_random_seed(0)

# Importiere Datasets (Training und Test)
import pandas as pd
poker_train = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/elihe/Documents/Studium Master/WS 19 und 20/Softwareprojekt/poker-hand-training-true.data", header = None, names= ['Farbe K1', 'Rang K1', 'Farbe K2', 'Rang K2', 'Farbe K3', 'Rang K3', 'Farbe K4', 'Rang K4', 'Farbe K5', 'Rang K5', 'Poker-Hand'])
poker_test = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/elihe/Documents/Studium Master/WS 19 und 20/Softwareprojekt/poker-hand-testing.data", header = None, names= ['Farbe K1', 'Rang K1', 'Farbe K2', 'Rang K2', 'Farbe K3', 'Rang K3', 'Farbe K4', 'Rang K4', 'Farbe K5', 'Rang K5', 'Poker-Hand'])

# Umwandlung der Outputs
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

# Trainings- und Testset in Input und Output verwandeln
X_tr = poker_train.iloc[:, 0:10].values
y_tr = poker_train.iloc[:, 10:11].values

X_te = poker_test.iloc[:, 0:10].values
y_te = poker_test.iloc[:, 10:11].values

encode = OneHotEncoder()
y_tr = encode.fit_transform(y_tr).toarray()
y_te = encode.fit_transform(y_te).toarray()

# Skalierung
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()

X_tr = sc.fit_transform(X_tr)
X_te = sc.transform(X_te)

# Kürzen der Datasets aufgrund der Rechenzeit
# train_test_split unnötig
X_train = X_tr[:5000]
y_train = y_tr[:5000]
X_test = X_te[:5000]
y_test = y_te[:5000]

# NN mit Keras erstellen
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

# Schritt für Schritt Layer hinzufügen
nen = Sequential()
# Input Layer: 10 Features als Input, 5 Units für den Hidden Layer
nen.add(Dense(512, input_dim = 10, activation = 'sigmoid'))
nen.add(Dense(512, activation = 'sigmoid'))
# Output Layer: eine Unit, erhält 5 Inputs vom Hidden Layer und 10 Outputs (für jeden möglichen Ausgang)
nen.add(Dense(10, activation = 'softmax'))

# Kompilieren
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop
# Loss-Funktion und Optimizer wählen
# Loss gibt den Unterschied zwischen Vorhersage und wahrem Wert an, sollte sinken
# Optimizer ist Methode, gibt an, wie die Gewichte im NN verändert werden müssen, sodass die Loss-Funktion fällt
nen.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=RMSprop(0.001), metrics=['accuracy'])

# batch_size = Anzahl an Samples pro Batch, Batch = teile Dataset auf
# epochs = ein ganzes(!) Dataset geht einmal durch das NN
nen_fit = nen.fit(X_train, y_train,epochs=30, batch_size=15, verbose=1, validation_split = 0.2, shuffle = False)

from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
np.set_printoptions(suppress = True)
y_vorh = nen.predict(X_test)
y_vorh = np.argmax(y_vorh, axis =1)

y_test = np.argmax(y_test, axis = 1)

confmat = confusion_matrix(y_test ,y_vorh)
print(confmat)
```

As Output i get only 8 things, but i would like to have 10, since my Output is possible from 0-9:

```
[[2155  359    0    0    0    0    0    0]
 [1525  562    0    0    0    0    0    0]
 [ 153   91    0    0    0    0    0    0]
 [  57   54    0    0    0    0    0    0]
 [   8   11    0    0    0    0    0    0]
 [  10    2    0    0    0    0    0    0]
 [   2    7    0    0    0    0    0    0]
 [   1    3    0    0    0    0    0    0]]
```

Where is the problem? How can i fix this?

Comment: Do you have in your `y_vorh` or `y_test` all 10 Labels?

Comment: so i have originally made the labels from 0-9 as vectors with zeros and ones (the onehotencoding) and after applying `np.argmax`i have just zeros and one as a vector

Comment: i really don't know how to decode my oneHotEncoding..if you know what i mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be because of these lines:

```
# Kürzen der Datasets aufgrund der Rechenzeit
# train_test_split unnötig
X_train = X_tr[:5000]
y_train = y_tr[:5000]
X_test = X_te[:5000]
y_test = y_te[:5000]
```

where you are excluding portion of the train and test data, which looks unnecessary. This most possibly excludes two of the classes from the test set, and therefore, creating a confusion matrix with 8 classes only. I expect removing the `[:5000]` would resolve the unexpected observation.